# How to get current authorized user inside a TFS work item tracking control in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, rest, tfs, tfs2014

I've been looking around and I've found that there's some REST API request that loads security groups and current identity:

```
tfs/DefaultCollection/Test/_api/_identity/ReadIdentitiesPageJson?__v=5
```

For example, it's called when Team Foundation Server's alert settings page is opened.

Now I can't figure out which client TFS object receives that API call resulting JSON, because I require that to get current identity GUID in order to create an alert using a custom work item tracking control.

My question is which client object holds such values?

Here's a sample JSON returned by the above HTTP request:

```
{
    "identities": [{
        "IdentityType": "group",
        "FriendlyDisplayName": "Build Administrators",
        "DisplayName": "[Test]\\Build Administrators",
        "SubHeader": "[Test]",
        "TeamFoundationId": "881e0467-b2c5-467c-b145-a2c5a0966463",
        "Errors": [],
        "Warnings": [],
        "IsWindowsGroup": false,
        "Description": "Members of this group can create, modify and delete build definitions and manage queued and completed builds.",
        "Scope": "Test",
        "MemberCountText": "0 members",
        "IsTeam": false,
        "IsProjectLevel": true
    }, {
        "IdentityType": "group",
        "FriendlyDisplayName": "Contributors",
        "DisplayName": "[Test]\\Contributors",
        "SubHeader": "[Test]",
        "TeamFoundationId": "9da39547-51c0-41a8-a1f5-88e3936f0736",
        "Errors": [],
        "Warnings": [],
        "IsWindowsGroup": false,
        "Description": "Members of this group can add, modify, and delete items within the team project.",
        "Scope": "Test",
        "MemberCountText": "0 members",
        "IsTeam": false,
        "IsProjectLevel": true
    }, {
        "IdentityType": "group",
        "FriendlyDisplayName": "Project Administrators",
        "DisplayName": "[Test]\\Project Administrators",
        "SubHeader": "[Test]",
        "TeamFoundationId": "f0611ae0-3048-4bee-bffe-91bf84921052",
        "Errors": [],
        "Warnings": [],
        "IsWindowsGroup": false,
        "Description": "Members of this group can perform all operations in the team project.",
        "Scope": "Test",
        "MemberCountText": "0 members",
        "IsTeam": false,
        "IsProjectLevel": true
    }, {
        "IdentityType": "group",
        "FriendlyDisplayName": "Project Valid Users",
        "DisplayName": "[Test]\\Project Valid Users",
        "SubHeader": "[Test]",
        "TeamFoundationId": "0a969c95-452c-43c2-84ae-b59be9be0d3e",
        "Errors": [],
        "Warnings": [],
        "IsWindowsGroup": false,
        "Description": "Members of this group have acess to the team project.",
        "Scope": "Test",
        "MemberCountText": "6 members",
        "IsTeam": false,
        "IsProjectLevel": true,
        "RestrictEditingMembership": true
    }, {
        "IdentityType": "group",
        "FriendlyDisplayName": "Readers",
        "DisplayName": "[Test]\\Readers",
        "SubHeader": "[Test]",
        "TeamFoundationId": "e61e08fa-ead6-46b1-87a6-a90610b70ba0",
        "Errors": [],
        "Warnings": [],
        "IsWindowsGroup": false,
        "Description": "Members of this group have access to the team project.",
        "Scope": "Test",
        "MemberCountText": "0 members",
        "IsTeam": false,
        "IsProjectLevel": true
    }, {
        "IdentityType": "team",
        "FriendlyDisplayName": "Test Team",
        "DisplayName": "[Test]\\Test Team",
        "SubHeader": "[Test]",
        "TeamFoundationId": "5985029c-5cc6-4f07-ad2f-c5bcf687804c",
        "Errors": [],
        "Warnings": [],
        "IsWindowsGroup": false,
        "Description": "The default project team.",
        "Scope": "Test",
        "MemberCountText": "0 members",
        "IsTeam": true,
        "IsProjectLevel": true
    }, {
        "IdentityType": "user",
        "FriendlyDisplayName": "mfidemraizer",
        "DisplayName": "mfidemraizer",
        "SubHeader": "win7vm-dev\\mfidemraizer",
        "TeamFoundationId": "a595782b-afac-46d0-a800-8245d13bb25b",
        "Errors": [],
        "Warnings": [],
        "Domain": "win7vm-dev",
        "AccountName": "mfidemraizer",
        "IsWindowsUser": true,
        "MailAddress": ""
    }],
    "hasMore": false,
    "totalIdentityCount": 7
}
```

**I need the `"TeamFoundationId": "a595782b-afac-46d0-a800-8245d13bb25b"` value.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up performing a HTTP/GET request to the whole `tfs/DefaultCollection/Test/_api/_identity/ReadIdentitiesPageJson?__v=5` REST API resource whenever I need to know current authenticated user GUID.

For now, it solves my issue!

Comment: @BeytanKurt Using Fiddler to debug HTTP request and analyzing one by one to understand what they're actually doing... Reverse engineering :(

Comment: nice job man, I still can't find any api resource, just using serkan inci's articles as a starting point and try to guess for the rest (: thanks again for the effort

Comment: @BeytanKurt I was developing TFS extensions to sell them online, but I'm considering publishing them on GitHub so other can check how to create TFS Web Access extensions. I still need to decide what to do...

Comment: That's so nice, it would be lovely if you give me a headsup about the final decision (:

Comment: can you give example of your get request to `tfs/DefaultCollection/Test/_api/_identity/ReadIdentitiesPageJson?__v=5`?  because each time when i send my request i get answer '401 аuthorisation Error'

Comment: @krabcore Think that at least when I did this, TFS REST API wasn't documented... it was a work of reverse-engineering to understand how TFS UI does requests and I tried the same request from my own code, and it worked. In the mean time, they could have been change the API or restrict who knows what. Well, in fact, I was developing some TFS add-in and I abandoned it... and now I wouldn't be able to reproduce the request :(

Answer (score 2):

I finally found something. I hope it helps.

`TFS.Host.TfsContext.getDefault().currentIdentity`  is bringing the **Current User** identity you need, I think.

Also, some more is available under current **TFSContext**, `TFS.Host.TfsContext.getDefault()`, like: **.currentUser** *(display Name)* and **.currentTeam**.

Comment: Interesting, I'll try this